# Previewing HTML in Java

Tags: java, html

What libraries/methods do you know of that can do some basic HTML representation in Swing? Can you comment on your experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of the Swing controls (like JLabel) can render basic HTML content. [JEditorPane](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html) can be used to display HTML pages. However, these controls are limited to [HTML 3.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32) support.

For a richer experience, I would use the [JDesktop Integration Components](https://java.net/projects/jdic/).

> JDIC provides Java applications with
>   access to functionalities and
>   facilities provided by the native
>   desktop. It consists of a collection
>   of Java packages and tools. JDIC
>   supports a variety of features such as
>   **embedding the native browser**,
>   launching the desktop applications,
>   creating tray icons on the desktop,
>   registering file type associations,
>   creating JNLP installer packages, etc.

Answer (score 2):

A good pure Java solution is [JWebEngine](http://www.inetsoftware.de/other-products/jwebengine). It render HTML 4 very good.

Comment: It's commercial license is about 2000USD

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this in a while, but a quick google search shows some possibilities:

- [Java Sketchbook: The HTML Renderer Shootout, Part 1](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2004/05/24/html-pt1.html)
- [Cobra: Java HTML Renderer & Parser](http://lobobrowser.org/cobra.jsp)

Are you trying to do this in an applet, or an application?  If it's an application (or signed applet) you could potentially instantiate IE or Firefox within your application.  [Webrenderer](http://www.webrenderer.com/index.php) acts as a Swing wrapper for this.

Answer (score 1):

Swing has a built-in compontent called [BasicHTML](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicHTML.html). I've never used it, but I think it should be sufficient for the basic stuff.

Answer (score 1):

This has historically been a major weak point for Java, IMO.  There are numerous ways to display limited markup, but very few that offer full featured HTML capabilities.  The previously mentioned JDIC component is one option, however it is considered a "heavyweight" component and therefore does not always integrate well with Swing applications.

I am hopeful, however, that the new Webkit based [JWebPane](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/ixmal/archive/2008/05/introducing_jwe.html) project will provide more advanced capabilities without all of the issues that we've had to deal with in the past.  And, of course, there are several commercial options as well ([IceBrowser](http://www.icesoft.com/products/icebrowser.html) is pretty good as an example).

Answer (score 1):

I've just used **[SwingBox](http://cssbox.sourceforge.net/swingbox/)** to display a quite simple HTML page, with good results.

The project includes a simple demo application which compares its `BrowserPane` component to `JEditorPane`, showing a far better result on complex pages (but still not comparable with a modern web browser).

The only issue I had is about unwanted scrollbars from the wrapping `JScrollPane`. The demo application seems to have the same problem. I can't tell where the issue originates. I'm using version 1.0.

Here a code fragment to show how simple is to use the component:

```
BrowserPane browserPane = new BrowserPane();
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(browserPane);
someContainer.add(scrollPane);

browserPane.setText("<html><b>Some HTML here</b></html>");
// or...
browserPane.setPage(new URL("http://en.wikipedia.org"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Came across [Lobo](http://lobobrowser.org/java-browser.jsp) java web browser the other day.

> Lobo is being actively developed with the aim to fully support HTML 4, Javascript and CSS2.

No experience with it though, but thought it may fit the bill for you.